# remapping tf frames

Tags: kinect, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm wondering if it is possible to remap tf frames from inside a launch file
(or other similar means) in the same way it is possible to remap topic names
of published topics?  My use case is that I have two Kinects between which I
would like to define a transform. However, the base frame_id for the kinect
is defined in the openni_driver.cpp file. This means that when I run two
Kinects they broadcast the same tf frame of /openni_rgb_optical_frame. Any
suggestions besides modifying the driver would be very much appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9149/remapping-tf-frames/) by [mkillpack](https://answers.ros.org/users/157/mkillpack/) on ROS Answers with karma: 340 on 2011-02-21

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Not possible with the current driver, and it turns out there is already a ticket on this: [#4688](https://code.ros.org/trac/ros-pkg/ticket/4688).

It seems like what should be done is to implement the (somewhat obscure, IMO) `~tf_prefix` parameter (which if I understand correctly, *should* always be implemented by producers of tf data.. maybe someone can comment). So in my case I set `tf_prefix` to, e.g., "`pelican1`", and the `frame_id`'s of the published point cloud and images are `/pelican1/<original_frame_id>`.

The [rewrite branch of the driver](https://github.com/ros-pkg-git/ni/tree/rewrite) appears to have the capability to set the frame names directly via a parameter which is even more flexible than `tf_prefix`, however it seems that `tf_prefix` should still be implemented.

---

Originally posted by [Patrick Bouffard](https://answers.ros.org/users/12/patrick-bouffard/) with karma: 2264 on 2011-02-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2